# Where to put unsubscribe email token in html code?

Tags: html, email, html-email

any ideas where to put unsubscribe token into a HTML code for an email? The HTML part of the source code looks like this:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="" class="button">Confirm</a> <a href="" class="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Basically, those are two blue buttons.

The unsubscribe token has this form - {{unsubscribeAll}} - and it should be put somewhere into the code. Unfortunately, I have no idea where exactly and there are no examples.

I am still learning HTML, CSS and Javascript, but I have zero experience with coding for email marketing.

Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Probably somewhere inside a URL that is specific for the mailing list service you are using and that we can't know.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple and easy.

First get the link which leads to the unsubscribe page.

Then add it to the first button, like this:

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="Link-to-unsubscribe-page" class="button">Confirm</a> <a href="" class="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

That's all and you must be leading to the unsubscribe page after you press the Confirm button.

Comment: Okay, and where do you put the token?

Comment: You must be getting the token from the website and most probably the whole link.. If you can share the screenshot of the page or the link you have, I can help you on what to do.